Latest version of bootstrap not rendering modal dialog in Visual Studio 2022
I have upgraded from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022.
I work on ASP.NET .NET Framework Webform based web applications. When I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022, I was warned that the current bootstrap version my application was using (3.4.1) had vulnerabilities and that I should upgrade to the latest. So here is what I needed to upgrade:
bootstrap - Old: 3.4.1 New: 5.3.3
AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap - Old: 3.4.1 New 5.2.3
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery - Old 3.4.1 New 3.7.1
Modal dialogs are generated in my .aspx files as follows:
<a href="#" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" class="anchor-btn" id="add-compp" data-target="#myModalAddressAddCP">Add Complainant</a>

After upgrading to the latest versions as listed above, the modal dialog box will NOT render when running in debug mode inside of Visual Studio 2022. If I Publish the web application and push it up to my IIS server, the modal dialog box will render just fine.
What gives?
I inspected the web pages as the web application was running in debug and there were a couple of errors where ID's were being used on the page that were duplicates. Funny that these errors were not displayed under Visual Studio 2019 but I digress. I thought that was the issue but even after fixing that, the modal dialog will still not render under those latest versions listed. When I went back to the older versions, the modal dialog will render just fine in debug mode.

use data-bs-toggle as shown in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/

Nope. That did not work.

Error analysis:
1.As VDWWD said, you should use "data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target.
2.bootstrap and AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap use incompatible versions.

You could consider installing only bootstrap (version 5.3.3) without installing AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap, or rolling back bootstrap to 5.2.0 to 5.2.4 (I used 5.2.3 for testing).
Related test code:
WebForm1.aspx
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- Trigger modal -->
                        <a href="#" data-id="2" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="anchor-btn" id="add-compp" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Add Complainant</a>
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                ...
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


@user115553, May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?
